# How do I access the <List> inside another <List>?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm having a tough time figureing out how to use the `ForEach` (or not use it) to print out the `Car` list I have inside the `Parent` list. I know obviously I can't do `XmlData.p.b.ForEach` and that the code below is just an example, as I'm going to have to do a lot of manipulation, but I just need to know how I can access the list in b inside the list p.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Address));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader("myXML.xml");
    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Address XmlData = (Address)obj;
    reader.Close();

    XmlData.p.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("Item in p!");
    XmlData.p.b.ForEach(b => Console.WriteLine("Item in b!"); // can't do this
}
```

XML Format:

Top: MyRoot

----------Target

-----------------Parent

----------------------------Cars

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Dealership")]
    public String dealership;
    [XmlElement("ZipCode")]
    public String zipCode;
    [XmlArray("Targets")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Parent")]
    public List<Parent> p = new List<Parent>();
}

public class Parent : Student
{
    [XmlElement("ParentName")]
    public String parentName { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [XmlElement("Owner")]
    public String owner { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public String age { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Cars")]
    public List<Cars> c = new List<Cars>();
}

public class Cars
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="BuildDependency/CarYear")]
    public String carYear { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "BuildDependency/CarMake")]
    public String carMake { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "BuildDependency/CarModel")]
    public String carModel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CarColor")]
    public String carColor { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CarMileage")]
    public String carMileage { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the list using [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
XmlData.p.SelectMany(p => p.b).ToList()
    .ForEach(b => Console.WriteLine("Item in b!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to iterate a list that is inside another list easy, you can do it within the first list iteration scope, something like (not gonna use lambda expressions but standard loops to keep it simple):

```
 for(int i=0; i<XmlData.p.Length; i++) {
   Console.WriteLine("Item in a!");
   for(j=0; j<XmlData.p[i].b.Length; j++) {
     Console.WriteLine("Item in b!");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just nest the second ForEach call:

```
   XmlData.p.ForEach(outer => outer.b.ForEach(inner => Console.WriteLine("Item in b!")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious that this doens't work, your code needs to be adapted so the b come's into the foreach class.

Your 2 nd call (iterating over list in list) should be:

```
XmlData.p.ForEach(p => p.c.ForEach(c => { Console.WriteLine("Item in C"); }));
```

I've written a very small demo project that I will share:

First some classes to make the project work:

```
public class MyRoot
{
    public List<Student> p = new List<Student>();
}


public class Student
{
    public List<Cars> c = new List<Cars>();
}

public class Cars
{
    public String carYear { get; set; }
    public String carMake { get; set; }
    public String carModel { get; set; }
    public String carColor { get; set; }
    public String carMileage { get; set; }
}
```

Then the initiazization:

```
var cars = new List<Cars>();
cars.Add(new Cars());
cars.Add(new Cars());
cars.Add(new Cars());
cars.Add(new Cars());

var student = new List<Student>();
student.Add(new Student() { c = cars });

var root = new MyRoot();
root.p = student;
```

So we create 4 cars and 1 student with the 4 cars.
In the root object we set the list of students to just 1 student with the 4 cars.

So we have the following situation:

```
-- Root
   -- Student
      -- Car
      -- Car
      -- Car
      -- Car
```

Now, to iterate over it, you need to do the following:

```
root.p.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("Item in 1"));
root.p.ForEach(p => p.c.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine("  Item in 2")));
```

This will give the output:

[image]

Note: When you have 2 students, 1 student with 4 cars and the other one with 2 cars, the output will become:

[image]

This is because first we're iterating over the students and then over the cars.
When you see for each student it's cars, you can nest your foreach. Your foreach will then looks like:

```
 root.p.ForEach(p =>
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Item in 1");
       p.c.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine("  Item in 2"));

   });
```

And then your output will be:

[image]

So, fairly long post but I hope it helps.